# keylistener doesn't work at the first

Tags: javascript

My program is like a reaction game. When press the "up arrow" the background change the color to red. And you need the press the button whithin 2 sec. And if you don't press then you lose else the game is running on.  But at the first 2 seconds you lose anyway but the game is going on well. So what's the problem with the code at the first 2 seconds?

My code:

```js
var ido = 2000;
var nyomott = 0;
var nemelso = 0;
// >> main()
function main() {
  nyomott = 0;
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var szin;

  switch (r) {
    case 0:
      szin = "red";
      break;
    case 1:
      szin = "green";
      break;
    case 2:
      szin = "yellow";
      break;
    case 3:
      szin = "blue";
      break;
  }

  var print = "<h1>" + "Pess the key: " + "</br>" + szin + "</h1>" + "</br>";
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = print;

  startTimer();
}

var ciklus = setInterval(startTimer, ido);

// >> startTimer() : This function starts the timer
function startTimer() {
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    if (nyomott == 0) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<h1>Lose</h1>";
      clearInterval(ciklus);
    } else {
      main();
    }
  }, ido);

}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(inEvent) {

  if (inEvent.keyCode == 38) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    nyomott = 1;
    console.log(nyomott);
  } else if (inEvent.keyCode == 404) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else if (inEvent.keyCode == 405) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  else if (inEvent.keyCode == 406) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #202020;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div onload="main()" id="results">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `function main()`, you set `nyomott = 0;` which satisfies the condition in `function startTimer()` which prints the 'Lose'.

**Made a few adjustments**

```js
//pushed your variables up to be above the event listener function to be able to set nyomotto = 1

var ido = 2000;
var nyomott = 0;
var nemelso = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(inEvent) {

  if (inEvent.keyCode == 38) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    nyomott = 1;
    console.log(nyomott);
  } else if (inEvent.keyCode == 404)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  else if (inEvent.keyCode == 405)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  else if (inEvent.keyCode == 406)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});

function main() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var szin;

  switch (r) {
    case 0:
      szin = "red";
      break;
    case 1:
      szin = "green";
      break;
    case 2:
      szin = "yellow";
      break;
    case 3:
      szin = "blue";
      break;
  }

  var print = "<h1>" + "Pess the key: " + "</br>" + szin + "</h1>" + "</br>";
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = print;

  startTimer();
}
var ciklus = setInterval(startTimer, ido);

// This function starts the timer
function startTimer() {
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    if (nyomott == 0) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<h1>Lose</h1>";
      clearInterval(ciklus);
    } else {
      main();
    }
  }, ido);

}
```

```css
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #202020;
    }

    div {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      font-size: 60px;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    h1 {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

```html
<div onload="main()" id="results">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but with that modification if you once press the button the game never will stop. But if i write "nyomott=0" It will bugging. How can i solve it to stop the game if no button is pressed?

Comment: You will have to change `nyomott = 0;` after 2000ms after it has been set to 1

Comment: Thank you very much. :D.